# Exception occurred when iterating though for loop that includes mouseEvent action

Tags: for-loop, javafx, foreach, indexoutofboundsexception

the following exception message appears when I iterate using NORMAL for-loop that includes mouseEvent action through radioButtons.

Message:
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

But when I iterate using for-each loop, there is no problem!

please help me, thank you

Concerned code part:

```
 HBox p1 = new HBox();
       
        RadioButton Red = new RadioButton("RED");
        RadioButton Blue = new RadioButton("Blue");
        RadioButton Black = new RadioButton("Black");
        
          ToggleGroup tg = new ToggleGroup(); 
        
          Red.setToggleGroup(tg);
        Blue.setToggleGroup(tg);
         Black.setToggleGroup(tg);
         
        
        RadioButton [] array = {Red,Blue,Black};
        
        p1.getChildren().addAll(Red,Blue,Black);
 
     
     i = 0;
     for(i = 0; i< array.length; i++){
         
         array[i].setOnAction(e->{
         
             System.out.println(array[i].getText());
         });
         
     }
```

Comment: Please expand this to a [mre], and indicate which line is throwing the exception.

Comment: Oh, wait: did you make `i` an instance variable for some reason? That would be one possible cause of the exception.

Comment: no it is static variable.

Comment: Well that's even worse. Why?

Comment: i don't know :(

Comment: Same explanation works for a `static` variable (which simply makes no sense anyway) as for an instance variable.

Comment: time to work through a basic tutorial about java language basics .. and stick to java naming conventions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing, because your question is incomplete, that you made the loop index `i` an instance variable, for some reason. I.e. you have something like:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Demo extends Application {
    
    // Guessing:
    private int i ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        HBox p1 = new HBox();

        RadioButton red = new RadioButton("RED");
        RadioButton blue = new RadioButton("Blue");
        RadioButton black = new RadioButton("Black");

        ToggleGroup tg = new ToggleGroup();

        red.setToggleGroup(tg);
        blue.setToggleGroup(tg);
        black.setToggleGroup(tg);

        RadioButton[] array = { red, blue, black };

        p1.getChildren().addAll(red, blue, black);

        i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            array[i].setOnAction(e -> {

                System.out.println(array[i].getText());
            });

        }
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(p1, 400, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

}
```

Here `i` is a property of the `Demo` instance (i.e. the application instance on which `start()` is invoked). In the `start()` method, `i` is initialized to `0` and then incremented each time you iterate the `for` loop. The `for` loop exits when `i` is no longer less than `array.length` (which is `3`), so when the `for` loop exits, `i==3`.

Consequently, when you press one of the buttons, the code

```
System.out.println(array[i].getText());
```

is executed. The value of `i` hasn't changed since the completion of the `for` loop, so this is equivalent to

```
System.out.println(array[3].getText());
```

and this throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, because the value indexes in the array are `0`, `1`, and `2`. Indeed, the complete error message is

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
```

Instead, you need to use a local variable for the index in the loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        array[i].setOnAction(e -> { /* ... */ });

    }
```

The problem now is that the lambda expression in the event handler cannot access the local variable `i` because it is not `final` (or "effectively final"). The solution to this is to "capture" the value of `i` on each iteration of the loop in a final variable:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        final int index = i ;
        array[i].setOnAction(e -> {
            System.out.println(array[index].getText());
        });

    }
```

Of course, you don't actually need the index; you just need the element of the array, so you could capture that instead:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        final RadioButton button = array[i] ;
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            System.out.println(button.getText());
        });
    }
```

This code is completely identical (in the sense that the compiler converts the following to the same thing) to:

```
    for (RadioButton button : array) {
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            System.out.println(button.getText());
        });
    }
```

which is by far the preferred form for a `for` loop.

Here's a fully-cleaned and working version of the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Demo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        HBox p1 = new HBox();

        RadioButton red = new RadioButton("RED");
        RadioButton blue = new RadioButton("Blue");
        RadioButton black = new RadioButton("Black");

        ToggleGroup tg = new ToggleGroup();
        RadioButton[] buttons = { red, blue, black };

        tg.getToggles().setAll(buttons);
        p1.getChildren().addAll(buttons);

        for (RadioButton button : buttons) {
            button.setOnAction(e -> {
                System.out.println(button.getText());
            });
        }
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(p1, 400, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you so much, yes i made it as a static variable, and the problem i think is; in the first time the loop will be executed, and in the second time, i value will be  3, so as you have mentioned, i should be local.

Comment: @AndroidWorld What do you mean "and in the second time"? The loop is only executed once.

Comment: i mean, when I press for example in the second radiobutton two times, the loop will be executed twice.

Comment: @AndroidWorld No it won't. The loop is only executed when the `start()` method executes.

Comment: if the loop is executed one time just, so how the action can be reused many times inside the loop ?

Comment: @AndroidWorld Because the loop creates an event handler on each iteration (so it creates three event handlers, one associated with each button). When you press the button, the appropriate event handler executes (which is just a single line). The loop doesn't get executed again: it's not part of any event handler. Sounds like you need to read some intro tutorials.

Comment: yes, indeed i have got the point, loop function is just to create actions to each radiobutton. Thank you so much and have a good day.

Comment: I think I have a suitable experience, but this excerise was not understood. and fortunately, I got the point.